# Prevent removing unhealthy target from target groups AWS LoadBalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have a load balancer with a single target. Every two or three weeks, this single target gets deregistered from the target group, and consequently, the load balancer returns 503 since there is no more target.

Here is the config of the target group

[image]

Question:
Is there any way to prevent the target to get deregistered from the target group?

(I understand that this target gets removed when it is unhealthy.)

Comment: Instead of preventing it, I think it would be better to fix that and identify why your targets get unhealthy.

Comment: Agree with Marcin. probably should fix the route cause. However we can disable health checks or even set health check status code to higher range. it can be any where from  200-499. what is the error code returned by Health check endpoint /health during this unhealthy period?